# VerifyCsrfToken, Auth & Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I'm going back to an old project, and the homepage need to be access when logged in, if not, you get redirected to /login. For that I'm using the Auth middleware, but when doing so, I get the following error (see bottom of post with the error and the full error on imgur).

I checked my `middleware` but don't actually have custom one, I also checked my code to see if I weren't using a weird `middleware` group or anything, and I can't seem to find an error for now.

In my `HomeController.php`, if I remove the usage of the `Auth middleware`, the script continue (but I have another error further along, about Roles & Permissions, which is normal)

```php
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Normally, I would expect to be redirected, but instead, I get this error : 
Trying to get property of non-object

Full error : 
[Refer this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q4lW.png)

I shall mention that I have this error on EVERY page that need authentification, and not on the one that doesn't, it's not limited to my `HomeController`

Thanks !

EDIT :
Here is the full controler where I use the middleware (even if I have the issue elsewhere too)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Sinistre;
use App\Appointment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $sinistres = null;
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
            $sinistres = Sinistre::all();
        } else {
            $sinistres = Auth::user()->sinistres;
            foreach(Auth::user()->societe AS $societe){
                $sinistres = $sinistres->merge($societe->sinistre);
            }
        }

        $sinistres = $sinistres->unique();

        $appointments = Appointment::orderBy('date_start', 'desc')->with(['sinistre', 'sinistre.user'])->take(8)->get()->reverse();
        return view('pages.home', [
            'sinistres' => $sinistres,
            'appointments' => $appointments,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post your code where you used the auth class

Comment: I edited the original post with my controller !

Comment: try adding `use Auth` above your class.

Comment: I already have ```use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;``` but if I replace it with ```use Auth;``` I get the same error

Comment: ahh sorry I miss that Auth class.

Comment: it can happen :) . Would you appear to have another idea ? I super stuck on this. And I edited my OP that I get the same error on every page that need authentication, not only my HomeController.

Comment: Check your RedirectIfAuthenticated.php handle function if it has `return $next($request);`

Comment: Make sure `StartSession::class` is before your `VerifyCsrfToken::class` entry in your `Kernel.php` under the `web` middleware

Comment: JoefreyR.Ramos : It has one, here is the code of the file : https://paste.laravel.io/e38866c4-576a-4aa8-9953-e8b5a4c87b95
@apokryfos : I checked it, and it is in the good order :)

Answer (score 0):

it might mean that you're not logged in try to add this one in the beginning of your index function in controller

```
    if(Auth::user()){
     //Your Code
    }else{
     return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, but it's never reached (I even tried to use ```dd('Are we reached ?');``` and it's not displayed.

Comment: Did you not change the login of Auth? or are you using customize?

Comment: Are you talking about the guard ? If yes, it's the standard one :)